# Java:incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int

Tags: java

Can someone help me fix my code? I'm trying to make a triangle using 2d arrays

```
public class Tri { 
public static void main(String [] args){ 

int rows; 
int columns; 
int i,j; 

int [][] arrayNumbers = new int[5][5]; 

arrayNumbers[0][0] = " "; 
arrayNumbers[1][0] = " "; 
arrayNumbers[2][0] = "*"; 
arrayNumbers[3][0] = " "; 
arrayNumbers[4][0] = " "; 

arrayNumbers[0][1] = " "; 
arrayNumbers[1][1] = "*"; 
arrayNumbers[2][1] = "*"; 
arrayNumbers[3][1] = "*"; 
arrayNumbers[4][1] = " "; 

arrayNumbers[0][2] = "*"; 
arrayNumbers[1][2] = "*"; 
arrayNumbers[2][2] = "*"; 
arrayNumbers[3][2] = "*"; 
arrayNumbers[4][2] = "*"; 

arrayNumbers[0][3] = " "; 
arrayNumbers[1][3] = "*"; 
arrayNumbers[2][3] = "*"; 
arrayNumbers[3][3] = "*"; 
arrayNumbers[4][3] = " "; 

arrayNumbers[0][4] = " "; 
arrayNumbers[1][4] = " "; 
arrayNumbers[2][4] = "*"; 
arrayNumbers[3][4] = " "; 
arrayNumbers[4][4] = " "; 

for(i=0;i<rows;i++){ 
for(j=0;j<columns;j++) { 
System.out.print(arrayNumbers[i][j] + " "); 
} 
System.out.println(" "); 
} 
} 
}
```

But I keep getting the error message "Java:incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int

Any idea where i'm going wrong? It keeps saying that it requires an int but it only found a String

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `String` values to your array. So this

```
int [][] arrayNumbers = new int[5][5];
```

should be

```
String[][] arrayNumbers = new String[5][5];
```

**or** you need to assign `int` values (like `1`, `2`, or 2<sup>31</sup>-1).

Answer (score 1):

Realistically, this should be done with a `char` array anyway, if it must be done with a 2D array at all.

Unless you were specifically told to make it an array, there are MUCH better ways of printing that shape to the console than to use an array. If you truly wish to store it in an array, a `char` array is the proper type though.

Statically populating the values though is a terrible waste of time and makes for messy code. If you consider how such a shape can be generated solely through the use of loop logic, you'll see that the same can be applied to initializing the array algorithmically.

Finally, your code, even fixed, doesn't generate a triangle, but rather a rhombus.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
int [][] arrayNumbers = new int[5][5];
```

with

```
String [][] arrayNumbers = new String[5][5];
```